# How do I protect my old devices against BlueBorne?

Tags: exploit, protection, bluetooth, blueborne

I have a bunch of Android devices for which there either is no patch to protect them against the BlueBorne exploit or I cannot install a patch without losing all the data.

The most obvious thing would be to disable BlueTooth. But we know that disabling WiFi/Bluetooth/etc does not actually disable them on a lot of devices (maybe most or even all?).

Is there a safe way to actually completely disable Bluetooth? Or another way to protect against BlueBorne without patching?

And is there a way to properly check if my device is still vulnerable against such an attack? (I just found some useless tools that claim to be able to tell if a device is vulnerable, while in reality they just claim that a device is always vulnerable if it has a certain MAC address.)

Oh, and I should mention: My devices are rooted and I only install open source software on them.